# behaviour of const_cast

Tags: c++, casting, lvalue, rvalue

I was reading about const_cast operator in c++

*1.First weird thing thing i can't understand is*

**const_cast operator syntax i.e.**

> > -const_cast--<--Type-->--(--expression--)--------------------><

what i have understand about this syntax is that it helps to cast away constness of an`expression`of type `Type` .But consider this code

```
class  ConstTest {   

private:
    int year;
public:
    ConstTest() : year(2007) {}
    void  printYear() const;
};

int main() {
    ConstTest c;
    c.printYear();
    return  0;
}

void ConstTest::printYear() const {
    ConstTest  *c  = const_cast<ConstTest*>(this);
    c->year  = 42;
    std::cout  <<  "This  is the  year "  << year  << std::endl;
}
```

Here in line `ConstTest *c = const_cast<ConstTest*>(this)`, I think that the const of `this` pointer should be cast away, but the output shows that it is the object which  `this` refers to that loses its const-ness.

I feel that the code should have been `ConstTest *c = const_cast<ConstTest>(*this)`, but this produces an error. I know i am wrong at many interpretations. Please correct them all.

*2.my second problem is the statement given below*

**The result of a const_cast expression is an rvalue unless Type is a reference type. In this case, the result is an lvalue.**

Why is this so, and why it is not true in case of pointers?

Comment: Best to avoid const_cast until you understand the language a lot better. It use is very dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it helps to cast away constness of an expression of type Type

No, `Type` is the type of the result, not the type of the operand.

> What i think is const of this pointer should be casted away

`this` has type `const ConstTest*`. `const_cast<ConstTest*>(this)` has type `ConstTest*`. That's what "casting away const" from a pointer-to-const means.

> I feel code should have been `ConstTest *c =
>   const_cast<ConstTest>(*this)`

The result of `const_cast<T>` has type T, that's how it's defined. Maybe you would have defined it differently, but tough luck, you don't get a `ConstTest*` by writing `const_cast<ConstTest>`, you get it by writing `const_cast<ConstTest*>`. Your preferred syntax is not available.

You can either do `ConstTest &c = const_cast<ConstTest&>(*this)` or `ConstTest *c = const_cast<ConstTest*>(this)`, so pick your favorite.

> The result of a const_cast expression is an rvalue unless Type is a
>   reference type. In this case, the result is an lvalue.
>
> why so and why it is not true in case of pointers?

It is true of pointers. `ConstTest*` is not a reference type, and the result of `const_cast<ConstTest*>(this)` is an rvalue. You then assign that value to the variable `c`.

Comment: Shouldn't `this` be `ConstTest* const`? `const ConstTest*` would mean that the data being pointed to is constant and thus can't be modified. Also what's an example of a ref type? Is the result of `const_cast<const ConstTest &> (*this)` a ref type? This can't be an lvalue since you can't assign to it.

Comment: @greatwolf: I meant what I wrote, in the `printYear` member function, `this` has type `const ConstTest*`. This does mean "pointer-to-const", although having a pointer-to-const does *not* necessarily mean that the data pointed to cannot be modified. It just means you can't modify it through that pointer. The result of `const_cast<const ConstTest&>(*this)` is indeed an lvalue, and has reference type. You are mistaken when you say that if something cannot be assigned to, it therefore must not be an lvalue. There are both modifiable and non-modifiable lvalues.