# type cast? template.... What is this cpp line of code?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [behaviour of const_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132315/behaviour-of-const-cast)

I need to understand what this line means

```
char A = strdup(const_cast<char*>(aString.c_str()));
```

I understand what strdup does from this:

[strdup() - what does it do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

strdup expects a const char pointer. Its the <,> part of the above line that confuses me.

Comment: `const_cast<char*>` is unnecessarily casting the result of `c_str()` from a `char const*` to a `char*` -- it's pointless here.

Comment: **Congratulations!** You found a bug!

Comment: That line doesn't mean anything; it won't compile. (Something about initializing a `char` with a pointer type.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const_cast< type >` is a C++ operator. You can read about it [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/typecasting/constcast.html).

I don't understand why it's needed here, since (assuming `aString` is of type `std::string`) `c_str()` already returns the `const char*` which `strdup` requires, and in any case adding `const`ness is done implicitly.

Only if the function receives a non-`const` parameter it's required, and even then it's usually not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The cast operator,

```
char * p = const_cast<char*>(q);
```

allows you to remove the constness (provided that q is a const char *).

In general `const_cast<T>` can be used to add or remove the const qualifier.

However, as `strdup` should be taking a `const char *` the cast here is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
                         aString
```

A variable, probably of type `std::string`

```
                         aString.c_str()
```

A `const char *` which points to nul-terminated array of `char`s

```
       const_cast<char*>(aString.c_str())
```

A cast, converting the value that is inside `()` to the type named inside `<>`. In this case, converting from `const char*` to `char*`. This is a C++-style cast (see also `static_cast<>()`, `dynamic_cast<>()`, and `reinterpret_cast<>()`).

```
strdup(const_cast<char*>(aString.c_str()));
```

As you say, you know what `strdup` does. Since the signature of `strdup` is probably `char* strdup(const char*)`, it turns out that this particular cast is pointless.